# convert nested ternary to basic if else

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand a javascript code that I've taken from an online source. But it is of full `?` and `:` symbols(ternary operators) and on top of that, this has multiple nested ternary operators.

Below is the code.

```
function () {
                var e = this,
                    t = e.$createElement,
                    n = e._self._c || t;
                return n("v-card", [e.responseCard.title.trim() ? n("v-card-title", {
                    staticClass: "red lighten-5",
                    attrs: {
                        "primary-title": ""
                    }
                }, [n("span", {
                    staticClass: "headline"
                }, [e._v(e._s(e.responseCard.title))])]) : e._e(), e._v(" "), e.responseCard.subTitle ? n("v-card-text", [n("span", [e._v(e._s(e.responseCard.subTitle))])]) : e._e(), e._v(" "), e.responseCard.imageUrl ? n("v-card-media", {
                    attrs: {
                        src: e.responseCard.imageUrl,
                        contain: "",
                        height: "33vh"
                    }
                }) : e._e(), e._v(" "), e._l(e.responseCard.buttons, (function (t, i) {
                    return n("v-card-actions", {
                        key: i,
                        staticClass: "button-row",
                        attrs: {
                            actions: ""
                        }
                    }, [t.text && t.value ? n("v-btn", {
                        attrs: {
                            disabled: e.hasButtonBeenClicked,
                            default: ""
                        },
                        nativeOn: {
                            "~click": function (n) {
                                e.onButtonClick(t.value)
                            }
                        }
                    }, [e._v("\n      " + e._s(t.text) + "\n    ")]) : e._e()], 1)
                })), e._v(" "), e.responseCard.attachmentLinkUrl ? n("v-card-actions", [n("v-btn", {
                    staticClass: "red lighten-5",
                    attrs: {
                        flat: "",
                        tag: "a",
                        href: e.responseCard.attachmentLinkUrl,
                        target: "_blank"
                    }
                }, [e._v("\n      Open Link\n    ")])], 1) : e._e()], 2)
            }
```

Can someone please convert this into a basic `if-else` block that is easily readable/understandable, I've read about this online, but due to the nested things, I'm very confused and unable to understand on how to do it.

Hi All, please don't take me wrong in asking such a basic question, I'm asking only because of the nested ternary operators and I'm unableto understand on how to break this down :-(

Thanks

Comment: Work on the outer layers first and than the inner

Comment: You probably will have better time if you inspect the _original_ version instead of the obfuscated one...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti this is the only version that I got :(

Answer (score 0):

I won't convert it for you.

A ternary operator is: `return condition ? answer1 : answer2`.

We can rewrote it like this:

```
if (condition)
  return answer1;
else
  return answer2;
```

A nested one would be: `return condition ? (condition2 ? answer1 : answer3) : answer2`

We can rewrote it like this:

```
if (condition) {
  if (condition2)
    return answer1;
  else
    return answer3;
}
else
  return answer2;
```

and so forth...

Example

```
var k = e.responseCard.title.trim() ? n("v-card-title", {
    staticClass: "red lighten-5",
    attrs: {
        "primary-title": ""
    }
}, [n("span", {
    staticClass: "headline"
}, [e._v(e._s(e.responseCard.title))])])
: e._e()

// condition is e.responseCard.title.trim()
// answer1 is n("v-card-title", bla bla bla...)
// answer2 is e._e()
```

in `if/else` world

```
var k;
if (e.responseCard.title.trim())
  k = n("v-card-title", bla bla bla...);
else
  k = e._e();
```

If you want to know more, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) has a nice documentation around ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip, but in my case it is something like this `return n(.......)` and the operators are inside `(`, and this is what confuses me alot and I'm trying to figure out on how I convert the first `return` statement(`return n(.......)`)? the sample that you've provided is for the inner part :(

Comment: @user3872094 you can ignore everything inside `(...)`.

Comment: you mean return `n(...)` can be ignored?

Comment: `n()` is a function. if  `k = n(...)`, then k is assigned to the value return by n.

Comment: Also, the thing that confuses me alot is the `,`, can you please let me know on how can I render this?

Comment: @user3872094 it is to separate parameters when you call a function like `Math.max(a , b)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157441/discussion-between-user3872094-and-aloisdg).